# Oracle PL/SQL: How to format the output

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, oracle11g, database

This is what I want:

```
    variable1:                1
    variable225:              ValueOfIt
    variable234234323:        $SomeAmount
    variable1234234:          Good
    variable1w23423423423423: September 11, 2001
```

This is something I have (I do type in manually the names of the variables like 'variable1'). I want something similar to variable.toString :-) and plus the dollar character and plus the amount of spaces between variable and value pairs so that they look cool.

```
variable1: 1
variable225: ValueOfIt
variable234234323: SomeAmount
variable1234234: Good
variable1w23423423423423: September 11, 2001
```

how can I format the output of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() in the above way?

I don't want to hardcode or type in manually the name of the variables and the distance separating the variable name and value of it? If a variable name is long, all values of variables should start positionally after the longest variable name. Also, I want to do dollar character in front of a numeric variable without hardcoding it like '$'.

Comment: In other words you want to pass a variable to DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE and have the name of the variable somehow available?

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(variablename,value) over a set of variables and their values. It should print exactly as it is shown above. What I dont want is manually type variable1 as string and the delimeters making it possible that values are one after another.

Comment: First, obviously, the first call to `DBMS_OUTPUT` cannot know about the subsequent calls to `DBMS_OUTPUT`.  That means that you have to determine the formatting before you call `DBMS_OUTPUT` for the first time.  Do you know before the first call everything that you want to output?  Can you create a procedure that accepts an array of variable names and an array of variable values and have that procedure call `DBMS_OUTPUT`?  How do you know whether to put a `$` before `SomeAmount` but not `1` if both are numbers?

Comment: Additionally, why do you care about the formatting?  `DBMS_OUTPUT` should not be relied on in a production environment since the client might not have it enabled and might never display the output to the user.  At most, `DBMS_OUTPUT` should be a debugging/ development tool in which case the format should be much less important

Comment: @JustinCave I can have 5 separate DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE following each other. This is a pure self-experiment, no production something like.

Comment: @JustinCave I want to get the formatting done with the separation. [shorter variable 3 times space value] [longer variable 1 time space value] please see my post above.

Comment: But, like I said, the first call doesn't know about the subsequent calls, so you'd have to determine the formatting before making the first call to `DBMS_OUTPUT`.  Given that, would a procedure that took a couple of arrays and made all 5 `DBMS_OUTPUT` calls be sufficient?

Comment: @JustinCave I can have five DBMS_OUTPUT calls. It is not full automatic as you think. Yes, I determined the format, but just don't know how to format it in this way.

Comment: Keep it simple. Something like `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(RPAD(variablename,30,' ') || value);`, and `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(RPAD(variablename,30,' ') || '$' || value);` for the dollar amount ones.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Exactly what I was looking for. RPAD cool!